# When is $\frac{a\sqrt{2}+b}{b\sqrt{2}+c}$ an integer?

Tags: rationalising-denominator

$\frac{a\sqrt{2} + b}{b\sqrt{2}+c}$ is a number, where $a, b, c$ are integers. What should be the condition for above number to be an integer? One possible solution is $a = b = c$. Other solutions would be a great help.

Comment: May you don't use chatroom language here? Also your question is not clear, you may want to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{a\sqrt{2}+b}{b\sqrt{2}+c} = t
\iff a\sqrt{2}+b=bt\sqrt{2}+ct
\iff a=bt, \ b=ct
\iff a=ct^2, \ b=ct
$$
because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.